# Using python to read text files and answer questions

Tags: python

I have this file animallog1.txt which contains information that i would like to use to answer questions using python. How would i import the file to python, which would latter be used
I tried

```
with open('animallog1.txt', 'r') as myfile
```

but this is not working and just outputs no such file or directory even though i am pretty sure it exists

```
animal_names, dates, locations = [], [], []

with open('animallog1.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        animal_name, date, location = line.strip().split(':')
        animal_names.append(animal_name)
        dates.append(date)
        locations.append(location)


 print(animal_names)
 print(dates)
 print(locations)
```

so this is the code that i have. animallog1.txt is the name of the file that i want to use.

However my output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "None", line 3, in <module>
builtins.FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'animallog1.txt'
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: Might be a problem with permissions. Also your question states "I have this file `animallog.txt`" and your code says `animal data.txt`.

Comment: Post a full code segment, along with a traceback if there is an error message.

Comment: Are you running the code from the directory containing the file?

Comment: added it up in question?

Comment: I am unsure if this will change anything, but just try `open('./animallog1.txt', 'r')`.

Comment: Make sure you are running the `python` command from the same directory that has the `animallog1.txt` file.

Comment: change your directory to the one containing `animallog1.txt` with a terminal and type `ls -l`. What is the output for the line with that txt file?

Comment: @Leonardo i have this text file would want to import it into my program so that it can be read later to answer questions. There is not output i just want to make it so that i can be read

Comment: In order for your program to find the file as written the `.py` file and the `.txt` file both need to be in the same directory. The code works fine on linux for me if they are in the same directory. I run the program like `python program_name.py`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you path is corret or try this:

```
file = open("sample.txt")
```

sample.txt is present in the current path, in my ubuntu it works.

Answer (score -3):

I would take a look at [this](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). So modifying your code could be like:

```
f = open('animal data.txt', 'r+');
f.readline(); //Do this until you've read your questions
f.write('Answer to the questions')
```

Comment: So change the w to an r.

Comment: `IOError: File not open for writing`

Comment: @Leonardo I was answering this question  as a python question not a linux permissions question as that is the way it was originally  presented.

Comment: That is fine Kyle, but your script as written is not a correct python program and the question does not involve writing. It turns out this is not a linux permissions issue either.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41786/discussion-between-kyle-and-leonardo)